# Display (javascript) Popup while page is loading

Tags: javascript, popup

I have been trying to find a simple solution for my problem but I can't. I have a page with while php clause that creates an html table and it takes a while to finish. I just want a popup window displayed when the user visits the page (on load) saying something simple like: "Page loading... Please wait". Can this be done with a javascript library? (exclusively with JS perhaps?) Every solution I've found messes with divs, classes, etc and I find it a bit difficult to use because my code is kind of unstructured at this time. Thanks.

Comment: You could put a JavaScript alert in the <head> of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the original webpage (HTML table) in a hidden `iframe` and have a loading message on the page. Then use the `onload` attribute to hide the loading message and display the `iframe`.

Edit: on a similar note, you could have a blank, edge-to-edge element covering the page content and use one of the numerous alternative alert options over that (e.g. [jQuery](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/)).  Then, using `body onload`, remove the blank element and alert; or replace the alert with a new one, notifying that loading is complete; etc.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the JS to do the "popup" I've enjoyed [SimpleModal](http://simplemodal.plasm.it/).

But more importantly, it sounds like you probably want to get away from the long-loading table being rendered inline.  Instead, render everything but the table to the page and display your "Loading..." indicator.  Then, make an AJAX request for the table.  Depending on your preference, the AJAX call can return the table with all the HTML or you can just retrieve the data in a JSON format and build the table on the client side.  This would be a very typical approach for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript toolkits would just automate the messing with the DOM that you want to avoid. That's how they work. JavaScript just scripts the DOM for this sort of scenario.

What you can do is look for a cheap cut-and-paste sample that shows how to make a big CSS box that will take over most of the screen real estate no matter what. Maybe something with an opaque area around the side. You put that content right after the `<body/>` tag and you can write a few lines of JavaScript that, on the `ready` event for the window just removes that box.

The thing about JavaScript modal dialogues that will be a problem for you is that most of them will have issues working when the DOM hasn't finished initializing (which is why almost all jQuery and Ext samples out there are wrapped in some `onReady` event handler).

Answer (score 0):

Well till your page is completely loaded you can use an iframe over the original frame. The basic idea is to load a frame which carries your load image and then after the DOM is fully loaded use say .ready handler to remove the frame and inset the iframe .